# Does Sabre BFM (soap) provides any method to sort the results?

Tags: soap, sabre, sabredav

I am totally new to sabre apis. I got a project which is already having "Bargain Finder Max" sabre soap api implemented. As far I have searched over the web I could only find this [documentation](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/instaflights_search) where it is mentioned that we can sort the API results by sending the parameters `sortBy` with the request. But this is `REST` api under Sabre whereas the one which is implemented on the project is [this](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max) under `SOAP`.

In the code the request sent and the response is also proper. For ex: It sends following request

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="3.4.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="3.4.0">
    <POS>
        <Source PseudoCityCode="PCC">
            <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
                <CompanyName Code="TN">TN</CompanyName>
            </RequestorID>
        </Source>
    </POS>
    <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
        <DepartureDateTime>2016-10-26T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="LHR"/>
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOM"/>
        <TPA_Extensions>
            <SisterOriginLocation LocationCode="LTN"/>
            <SisterOriginLocation LocationCode="LGW"/>
            <SegmentType Code="O"/>
            <CabinPref Cabin="Y" PreferLevel="Preferred"/>
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
    <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="2">
        <DepartureDateTime>2016-11-04T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOM"/>
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHR"/>
        <TPA_Extensions>
            <SisterDestinationLocation LocationCode="LTN"/>
            <SisterDestinationLocation LocationCode="LGW"/>
            <SegmentType Code="O"/>
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
    <TravelerInfoSummary>
        <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
        <AirTravelerAvail>
            <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
        </AirTravelerAvail>
        <PriceRequestInformation CurrencyCode="GBP"/>
    </TravelerInfoSummary>
    <TPA_Extensions>
        <IntelliSellTransaction>
        </IntelliSellTransaction>
    </TPA_Extensions>
</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

which generates proper results. But now I need to sort the results according to minimum time and price. Please guide me if the api provides any sorting method or I have to create my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as you imagined that documentation is not for *Bargain Finder Max* (BFM), but another service called *InstaFlight*, the actual documentation that you need to check is here:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max/resources

Now, regarding your actual question, the only thing that would help you sorting would be to use the priorities, you need to set them from 1 to 4 in the order you want.

```
<PriceRequestInformation CurrencyCode="GBP">
    <TPA_Extensions>
        <Priority>
            <Price Priority="1"/>
            <DirectFlights Priority="2"/>
            <Time Priority="3"/>
            <Vendor Priority="4"/>
        </Priority>
    </TPA_Extensions>
</PriceRequestInformation>
```